# Use `**` but ignore directories that match the specified name

Tags: javascript, glob, minimatch

I am looking for a glob that matches all descendant directories except those of a specific name. For instance `foo/**/*.js` matches all `*.js` files that are descendents of `foo/`, which is good; the extension of that pattern that I want ignores any descendants that are under a `__tests__` directory.

```
foo/
  file01.js
  __tests__/
    ignore01.js
  bar/
    file02.js
    __tests__/
      ignore02.js
      qux
        ignore04.js
    baz/
      file03.js
      __tests__/
        ignore03.js
```

What I have tried:

- `foo/**!(__tests__)/*.js`
- `foo/!(__tests__)**/*.js`
- `foo/**!(__tests__)**/*.js`
- `foo/**/!(__tests__)/*.js`
- `foo/!(__tests__)/**/*.js`

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but using an expansion should work here:

```sh
foo/{,**/!(__tests__)/}*.js
```

This expands to two conditions which should match your paths, namely

```sh
foo/*.js
foo/**/!(__tests__)/*.js
```

You can read more about globs [over here](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer).

Comment: Thank you for that. I will test whether it works on my machine.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that will ignore `foo/baz/file02.js`.